# string.Format give wrong thousand seperator in html razor C# block

Tags: c#, string.format

string.Format("{0:#,0}",19091507)

string.Format give wrong thousand seperator in html razor C# block
Expected Output : 19,091,507
Current Output : 1,90,91,507

Please help me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @Christos  please reply me i u have any idea about that

Answer (score 0):

You can try following.

```
        int @value= 19091507;
        Console.WriteLine(@value.ToString("#,#.##", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```

For me following is also working.

```
        int @value= 19091507;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:#,#.##}", @value));
```

You can also try.

```
        int @value= 19091507;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"),"{0:#,#.##}", @value));
```

It depends on your culture.

Comment: Thank you so much it's working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. If it is working for you then it is good if you accept that answer.

Comment: if i number is 6 digit it not display as expected ,i have to switch IN culture for show 6 digit  Number 

U.S Culture Shown as: 564,717 , Expected : 5,64,717